# Beginner - Median SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, median

I have been trying to get the median from my SSAS cube but in vain.

I have a `fact` table with a sale price and FK for `dimensions` (time, sale size (S-M-L), and shop).

PROBLEM: can't calculate median with respect to the 3 dimensions

Calculated member, not working:

```
MEDIAN([Sale Size Dim].[App Size].Members,[Measures].[Amount])
```

How can I make it work ? Thanks

Comment: how do you know that it is not working. what is the MDX query you are using and how exactly do you want the MEDIAN to behave ?

Comment: please can you add the rest of the mdx scipt so we can see how you are using the median function?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression will calculate the `MEDIAN` across all sizes. What you probably need is something like this:

```
 MEDIAN([Sale Size Dim].[App Size].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN,[Measures].[Amount])
```

Comment: how can this ever work? The definition in MSDN is located here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145570.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I actually missed the CHILDREN. Updating

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the addition of the keyword EXISTING helps?

```
MEDIAN(
   EXISTING [Sale Size Dim].[App Size].Members
  ,[Measures].[Amount]
)
```